# Why can't I edit any questions anymore? Is it a bug or...?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

It has happened for me after creating [sexist-language tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexist-language) and being approved as a new tag. The edit option under all questions has been inactive for me. I wanted to add an explanation and found this weird false reply after clicking on the "help us creating it" option:

[Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days.](https://english.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1378)

It sounds very angry and meaningless! I didn't get what it means as I didn't find any rule in the FAQ that stops users to edit questions until they gain +1000 reputation by this. I have gained 94 points by editing and rarely happened that one or two out of all my edits be rejected that it was only because of different tastes of mods not a mistake in editing by me.

Can one of mods please explain what has happened here? Is it a new unreadable rule out of FAQ or a personal taste of one of mods?

Please make it clear!

Comment: Pretty much all of your comments here are wrong, so I've deleted the entire thread. The folks who tried to explain that this is an automated block were right, you were not - arguing with them doesn't make you any *less* wrong. If you think the wording of the message displayed should be changed, post that as a [meta-tag:feature-request]; if you think you should've been notified earlier that you were on the cusp of a ban, then [support this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor).

Answer (score 10):

You can view your history of suggesting edits here: https://english.stackexchange.com/users/37324/persian-cat?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

The ban only looks at *recent* suggested edits - this is to prevent someone from building up a history of good edits and then spamming the queue with a large number of bad ones.

Here are your most recent suggested edits (drawn from the list above):

- [Replaces quotes with bold+italics](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26725) (Rejected)
- [Added "sexist-language" tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26712) (Approved)
- [Added "sexist-language" tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26689) (Rejected)
- [Added "sexist-language" tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26688) (Rejected)
- [Added list of options to a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26683) (Rejected)
- [Title and formatting changes](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26681) (Approved)
- [Added "offensive-language" tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26680) (Rejected)
- [Added "offensive-language" tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26677) (Rejected)
- [Title and formatting changes](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26676) (Rejected)
- [Title and formatting changes](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26675) (Approved)
- [Title and formatting changes](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26673) (Rejected)
- [Minor capitalization and grammar changes](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26671) (Approved)
- [Title and formatting changes](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26670) (Rejected)
- [Changed "phrasing" tag to "vocabulary"](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26669) (Rejected)

Obviously, a fairly high number of your *recent* edits have been rejected. You should revisit these edits and attempt to discern what you could have done differently to avoid this outcome. Here are a few notes I made while reviewing the reviews:

- Replacing quoted text with italics or similar doesn't seem to go over well. Unless you have a very good reason for making such changes, I would abandon that approach: generally-speaking, actual *quoted text* should either be placed between quotation marks, or in a blockquote (by prefixing a paragraph with `>` in Markdown). Italics (and bold) are for *emphasis* not *quotation*.
- Tags generally have specific meanings within the context of the site. For instance, "vocabulary" [does *not* mean what you apparently think it means](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/vocabulary/info). It pays to be aware of this before trying to use a tag.
- You should generally have a *very* good reason to create new tags.
- You should avoid creating or using [meta-tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) - tags should always describe the content of the question in some fashion. So if a question is *about* sexist language, or *about* offensive language, those tags might be appropriate - but if you simply feel that the question *contains* sexist (or offensive) language, that's not a good use for a tag (it might be a good reason to flag, if you feel strongly about it).
- You should strive to communicate both the nature of, and reason behind your changes in the revision comment when submitting edits. "Added a new tag! :)" does the former, but doesn't explain *why* a new tag is necessary. If there's a chance your edit will be misinterpreted, try to avoid misunderstandings by being clear about what you're looking to accomplish ahead of time.

---

As a final note: this is at least the second time I've seen you asking for help with a tone that comes off as overtly hostile to other readers, both in the post itself and in the follow-up comments. I highly recommend that you adopt a bit of humility and politeness when seeking information about a system that you are obviously struggling to understand; failing to do so is very likely to cause you problems here in the future.

Answer (score 6):

Currently the system gives a user a “free” reject for every three approvals less than one week old. In your case, your 54 approvals count as 18 “free” rejects.

Currently the system auto-bans when a user has 5 rejects (other than “free” rejects) less than one week old. In your case, apparently the system auto-banned you because you have 23 − 18 = 5 rejects less than one week old.

If this system seems strict, bear in mind that it replaced an earlier system which banned the user for 5 rejects in one week regardless of how many approvals they earned.[¹](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days)

Answer (score 4):

It's not a bug. It's an autoban. This [question and answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled) on Meta.SO might help you.

All high rep users have the ability to vote on suggested edits, so this is unlikely to be a specific mod action. For instance, I don't even get a chance to see most suggested edits because our community processes them first.

Also, the autoban is triggered when many suggested edits are rejected, not just one or two.

If you are concerned about the moderators, you can email team@stackexchange.com and explain the situation to them.

Comment: So does your autoban mean 23 out of 54 as too many? What a weird autoban has been created. I think the creator needs to get some lessons in maths. Team?! No I have no time for it as I think I will get the same answers. The authority!Thanks! :)(

Comment: @Persia I don't know what the criteria for the autoban is. You could ask on Meta.SO if you are interested. They might tell you.